# ICACLS and unicode file/folder names - the tool changes characters and is unable to locate files/folders

Tags: unicode, icacls

I'm trying to fix permissions on users folders created with Folder Redirect. I need "Domain Admins" group to have full access. Everything works as long as folder name is not using unicode characters. And there a quite many folders like that :(
For example: ICACLS changes Ł to A, ł to B...

```
D:\Path\Path>icacls ęóąśłżźćń
icacls ↓ˇ♣[B|zD
↓ˇ♣[B: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
'zD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\Path\Path>icacls ĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ
icacls ↑Ë♦ZA{y♠C
↑Ë♦ZA{y♠C: Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I tried changing chcp to various values, nothing worked (by default my cmd uses 852). Tried changing fonts used by cmd, also didn't help.

Is it possible to make ICACLS understand Polish? :)

EDIT: weird thing is, when i use ICACLS as 'system', it behaves like above. When used with mu user rights, it properly reads unicode characters.

EDIT2:
where icacls ran as user

```
C:\Users\Administrator.CEO>where icacls
C:\Windows\System32\icacls.exe
```

where icacls ran as system

```
C:\Windows\system32>where icacls
C:\Windows\System32\icacls.exe
```

i try to run icacls commands from cmd window, not as .bat or .cmd files, for example

```
icacls "D:\FolderRedir\IT\Stanisław Smólski" /grant "Domain Admins":F
```

output changes ł and ó to other characters, and icacls is unable to locate the file/directory

Comment: Please [edit] your question to refine your [mcve]. Are you sure that you call `iCACLS.exe`? Do you run a batch file (extension `.bat` or `.cmd`)? Did you _name_ your batch file `icacls` (+extension `.bat` or `.cmd`)? (the latter is wrong…) Please show us result from `where icacls` (with both _system_  an _user_ rights).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly was wrong - we had a problem with one ups today and server was forcefully restarted. After the restart (and unexpected Windows update that used the restart oportunity) i tried icacls again, and... it worked with all the Polish characters.
I guess the problem solved itself.